# Проверить значение ключа обьекта JS

Tags: javascript

Как правильно проверить значение ключа orders?

```
let obj = {orders:[null]}
```

Так можно, но на мой взгляд выглядит криво

```
if(obj.orders[0] !== null) {...}
```

Comment: нужно именно на `null`, или просто, что там не отрицательное значение? Зачем вообще нужна записать `[null]`?

Comment: что-то мне кажется что достаточно просто `orders: null`, а не `[null]`

Comment: С сервера приходит или null или обьекты

Comment: @Lex прям так в массиве и приходит?

Comment: Да, присылают или [null] или [{},{},{}]

Comment: obj.orders[0] !== null ? почему бы и нет?

Comment: Я так и сделал, мне показалось, что есть более феншуйный метод

Comment: феншуйный - это возвращать null, а не массив с null в нем.

Comment: спасибо, да, Вы правы, буду с беком говорить

Comment: Спорный вариант возвращать null - Мартин Р. Чистый код: создание, анализ и рефакторинг. Библиотека программиста. —
СПб.: Питер, 2013.   - стр. 139